# Insert a matrix in matplolib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to import a `numpy` matrix in a `matplotlib` plot. Let's say that I have this matrix:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [ 9,10,11,12]]
```

In a scale from 0 to 3 of the x axis, I want to plot the points

```
(0,1), (0,5), (0,9), 
(1,2), (1,6), (1,10), 
(2,3), (2,7), (2,11), 
(3,4), (3,8), (3,12)
```

This is the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
plt.grid(True)
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(j,matrix[i][j],'ro')

plt.show()
```

and this is the outcome:

[image]

Yet, if I have to use a large array of let's say (1000x1000) elements or more, this procedure is going to be extremely slow. I wander if there is a method in `matplotlib` in which the array is inserted in the plot without the need to "manually" insert each one element.

Also *(and I know that this should be a different question)* if the above question solved, is there an easy way to clear the drawing in order to update with a new matrix?

Comment: Without the loop: `plt.plot(matrix.T, 'ro')` ?

Comment: @Michael Szczesny Finally that was much simpler than I thought. The `plt.plot(matrix.T, 'ro')` does the job fine. If you could also provide me a way of how to clear the plot as well, that would be excellent. Thanks.

Comment: build out your coordinates first, then plot once

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny's is simpler than my answer below -- I hadn't seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array([
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [ 9,10,11,12]])
b = np.tile(np.arange(a.shape[1]), (a.shape[0], 1))

plt.scatter(b, a)
```

[image]

Comment: This is more convoluted than just doing `plt.plot(matrix.T, "ro")`